# get ip address with javascript without using ajax, jquery or another library

Tags: javascript, html, ip, host

I want get the ip address of my clients, but i only want to use pure Javascript without another library

I searched in the internet but i can't found a way to do it, I'm a student so, I have no choise, I can use only JavaScript

I found this, but it doesn't work

```
function myIP(){ var vi="uses java to get the users local ip number";
        var yip2=java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();   
        var yip=yip2.getHostAddress();
      return yip;
    }
```

Comment: I'd say there is no (and shouldn't) reliable way (if at all there is a way) to do this with just JavaScript..

Comment: no i don't duplicate nothing... please i need help or a good explanation

Comment: There is no way bro. Only server can get that info.

Comment: ok can you tell me the reasons why or a documentation to validate my posible answer

Comment: when you say javascript do you mean on the client side or like nodejs on the server?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small library which does what you are asking but I really don't know the credibility of this library.

Its called `l2.io`. Here is the link for that.

http://l2.io/

Answer (score 0):

You could use **telize**, a third party, and make a jsonp request:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function getip(json){
    document.write("My IP address is : ", json.ip);
}
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=getip"></script>
```